# Kali Rolling Release Upgrade 2hr Login and Frozen Desktop

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade, desktop, rolling-release

I upgraded Kali to Rolling Release today and the install went smoothly until I restarted after the installation.

It took about 2 hours to get from the login screen to the desktop. The screen is now frozen and my icons are missing from my dock. But the mouse and keyboard still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot to maintenance mode or non-graphical login (probably by appending "3" to the kernel line), and try to update this way (if it was a hiccup, fixes might be available by now).

If not, you could look at the logs to see what went wrong (and report it).

Comment: I am able to get in to the non GUI mode and have full root access unfortunately this being my only computer the only way I will be able to display logs is via an image.... Let me know what your looking for specifically and I will post it

Comment: Logs are text files, they predate GUIs by *decades*...

Comment: I understand that I have no way of exporting the text file

Comment: ok so ive managed to acces my desktop using my old 4.0.0 kernel.... what log file do you want??